# Place one div with price above another one

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a small eStore powered by wooCommerce plugin on default Wordpress theme "Unite".

I'd like to modify a default price layout which looks like this for now:

[image]

Css snippet:

```
<span class="price">
    <del>
        <span class="amount">2,200.00&nbsp;руб.</span>
    </del> 
    <ins>
        <span class="amount">1,500.00&nbsp;руб.</span>
    </ins>
</span>
```

I need to place both prices in one row that it wouldn't break the grid.
For now, it renders list of watches this way:

[image]

How could I modify css rules to place all prices in one row using css and pseudo-elements? Thank you!

Comment: `display: inline-block`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, but you'll need to change the font sizes so they don't exceed the width of your product container...
/* Added a imaginary width to the span.price, not sure how wide your products are? */

```css
span.price {
  width: 220px;
  display: block;
}
span.price del,
span.price ins {
  float: left;
}
span.price del {
  width: 35%;
  font-size: .7em;
}
span.price ins {
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<span class="price">
    <del>
        <span class="amount">2,200.00&nbsp;руб.</span>
    </del> 
    <ins>
        <span class="amount">1,500.00&nbsp;руб.</span>
    </ins>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works in my case with some editions!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Float or displat:inline-block for show in line spans ... 
discount label : Float:left/right
Price label : Float